# Convention - remove parentheses of n-tuple in function evaluation

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f \colon X^2 \to Y$ where $X, Y$ are two sets.

For $x_1, x_2 \in X$ I can write $f((x_1, x_2))$.
But can I remove the parentheses, i.e. $f(x_1, x_2)$?

If yes, can I generalise on the cartesian product?
My question is a little bit tricky because the cartesian product on sets is not associative.
For example, if $g \colon X^2 \times Y \to Z$, for $x_1, x_2 \in X, y \in Y$ can I write $g(x_1, x_2, y)$ or because of the non-associativity of the cartesian product on sets must I write $g((x_1, x_2), y)$?

Any advice on mathematical writing conventions for this text is appreciated!

Comment: Vepain, you can remove the parentheses notwithstanding the non-associativity of the cartesian product.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Can you give an example of a misuse please?
I you have an example in graph theory it would be nice :)

Comment: OK, that's what I thought, thanks!